# Unzip a zip file whose content's name is too long in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, rename, mv, zip

I have a zip file, `sample.zip`, which contains a PDF whose name is too long. I tried to unzip it in Ubuntu terminal through

```
unzip sample.zip
```

however, it shows an error that "File name too long". Is there a way to tackle this issue? For example, is there any way to rename the content of the zip file (which in this case is a PDF) without extracting it? If yes, then I may rename it and extract it later.

Comment: Curiosity. The standard file systems I'm familiar all have a file name length limitation of 255 bytes. Where was the zip file created with the extra-long name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unzip the file to a pipe and redirect the output to a new file.

```
unzip -p sample.zip > new.pdf
```